# Using jQuery Resizable Helper on a Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-resizable

How can I use the [Helper](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#helper) functionality from [jQuery Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable) (which only displays a frame while the container is resized) on a [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?

Comment: since `resizable` option of dialog is only a boolean, doubtful you can without editing the actual widget source itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11102228/238722) explains how to achieve what you are looking for. Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VheS/2/).

The answer has one flaw: the resize handle goes underneath the dialog if it is being shrunk. This is solved through `z-index: 10000 !important;`. The jsFiddle linked here includes the fix.

---

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 2px dotted #00F;
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$("#dialog").dialog().dialog('widget').resizable('destroy').resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/specify-drag-and-resize-option-for-dialogs it should be possible by doing:

```
dlg.dialog('widget').resizable('option','helper','ui-resizable-helper')
```

But unfortunately there is a bug in jQueryUI (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6723) that blocks this from working.

One possible solution would be to use jQueryUI `resizable` instead of `dialog`. Depends on how heavy you rely on `dialog`'s functionality.